# Textbox with MaskEditExtender accepting minus sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to make a `textbox` that allows negative Time.

This is the code I'm trying to fix, but all solutions I find about it (changing `regex`, putting `AcceptNegative="Left"`) are not working as expected.

What am I missing?

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="txtHsTotal" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="componentSize120 txt-Label cursorHand"
    TabIndex="8" 
    Text="00:00">
</asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender
    ID="MaskedEditExtender_HsTotal"
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtHsTotal"
    Mask="99:99"
    OnInvalidCssClass="txt-TextBox-Error"
    MaskType="Time"
    ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"
    AcceptAMPM="True"
    AcceptNegative="Left"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator
    ID="MaskedEditValidator_HsTotal"
    runat="server"
    ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender_HsTotal"
    ControlToValidate="txtHsTotal"
    ValidationExpression="^-?([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$"
    Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: If it is the regex, maybe you should use `^-?([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$` to allow time values like `1:34`. If that is not what you mean by *not working as expected*, the reason should be somewhere in the code.

Comment: The issue is: even with the Regex and AcceptNegative="Left", I can't put the minus sign in the textbox. I though this was clear.